# Corpora Tools for Cataloguing and Phonetic Markup?

Tags: phonetics, corpora, tools

I'm creating an annotated corpus of poetry annotated with accent, alliteration, rhythm, and phonetics. I'd like it to handle and input poetry in multiple languages but still be able to add markup (perhaps in layers) for the phonetic markings.

It sounds to me like an XML database with a front-end tool for entry and another one for display and concordance.  But it also sounds like something that must already exist somewhere. Who knows what software is already available and which ones are free?

Comment: I'm voting for closing this question. Possible duplication of: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12144/annotation-tool-to-annotate-a-cross-lingual-corpus/16973#16973

Comment: Although the answers to the question cited by @Adel are quite comprehensive, the two questions are different IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Considering manual annotation, there is [WebAnno](https://github.com/webanno/webanno), a very flexible annotation tool that allows you to define your own annotation layers.

It has a web user interface and allows for collaborative annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this related question is the best I'm likely to get:

[annotation tool to work with XML Schema](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6562/annotation-tool-to-work-with-xml-schema?rq=1)